# What is the correct usage of "meanwhile"?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

I see *meanwhile* a lot; I use it a lot;  yet I'm not sure about the formal rules when it's applicable.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Meanwhile" is a word meaning "while something else is happening." It is used to bridge references to two actions that are happening simultaneously.

> I was sitting in my car at the train station, waiting for my wife, who was supposed to be home on the 6:40. Meanwhile, she was on a different train going to God-knows-where.

Comment: It sounds close to the same, but 'in the mean time' is different: 'She'd called to say she'd be on the 6:40 but, in the mean time, her friend had lured Imelda into shoe-hunting expedition. '

Comment: @Pete Wilson: The question was about *meanwhile*. Where are you getting "in the mean time"?

Comment: As I said: It *sounds* close to the same, but 'in the mean time' is different. It's a good idea to forestall confusion, imo, before the inevitable question appears. That's the intent of the comment. Objections?